# Kotlin Multiplatform concurrent mutability iOS vs Android

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm aware that Kotlin/Native has very specific rules in regards to [mutability of objects between threads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-concurrency-overview.html).

However to my surprise, I've found that when running unit tests from commonMain (deployed to androidTestDebug), **I am able to change mutable states on different threads**. For example this works fine when changing the value in `MyData`:

```
data class MyData(var value : Int = 0)

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
  val myData = MyData()
  val newContext1 = newSingleThreadContext("contextOne")
  val newContext2 = newSingleThreadContext("contextTwo")

  launch (newContext1) {
    myData.value = 1
  }
  launch (newContext2) {
    myData.value = 2
  }
}
```

However if I run this while targeting iOS, it crashes, giving me `kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException`. This is what I would expect to happen on both platforms. I'm new to KMM, but **why aren't concurrent mutability rules enforced when running commonMain code on JVM**?

Also **is there a way to force mutability rules on the JVM so that tests fail on Android just as they would on iOS**? I think this would help ensure platform consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn’t crash on Android.

Kotlin native creates Native code from Kotlin, that’s why there’s a need in it’s own concurrency model.

For android part this is plain kotlin code, so JVM concurrency model can be used, and as any other kotlin code that mutates a variable it shouldn’t crash.

I don’t think there’s a way to make it crash on Android.

In kotlin 1.6.0 this [should be changed](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/08/try-the-new-kotlin-native-memory-manager-development-preview/) so this code is not gonna crash on both platforms